# Prove that $\lim(x_n)=0$ using definition of limit of sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n:=\dfrac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\space\forall \space n\in N$

Use the definition of limit of sequences to prove that $\lim(x_n)=0$

I tried to use $e^n>n+1\Rightarrow n>\ln(n+1)$ but that gives me $\dfrac{1}{n}<\dfrac{1}{ln(n+1)}$ which doesn't seem of much use.

Please help.

Comment: How elementary is the proof supposed to be? Can you use the property that $\ln n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$? If yes, then do you see how it follows from that?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Actually that limit is not known yet at the stage of book I am at, so I don't think you can use it in the proof

Comment: I see. What is the definition of $\log$ that you use? The inverse of $\exp$?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $0$, you to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural $N$ such that for every natural number $n > N$, you have $\vert x_n\vert < \epsilon$.

So let's take $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrarily small. We have
$$
\dfrac{1}{\ln(n+1)} < \epsilon
$$
if and only if
$$
n+1 > e^{1/\epsilon}.
$$
So you can fix some natural number $N$ larger than $e^{1/\epsilon}$ and you will have for every natural number $n > N$ that (using monotonicity of log and positivity of the sequence)
$$
0 < x_n < x_N < \epsilon,
$$
which gives the result.

Comment: For fixing a natural number $N>e^\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, have you used archimedean property?

Comment: I don't know how you defined the reals and what tools you have at your disposal, but if you have access at the floor function, you can use $N := \lfloor e^{1/\epsilon}\rfloor + 1$. If not, it depends on your definition of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that for any real number $\epsilon>0$ you can find an integer $N_{\epsilon}>0$ such that $x_n<\epsilon\;\forall n > N_{\epsilon}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

First, a word on notation.

Let $\mathbb{N}$ refer to the positive integers.

Let $\mathbb{N}_>$ refer to the upward closed sets of $\mathbb{N}$.

$$ \mathbb{N}_> \stackrel{\text{def}}{=\!=} \{\{1, 2, 3, 4, \cdots\}, \{2, 3, 4, 5 \cdots\}, \{3, 4, 5, 6 \cdots\}, \cdots \} $$

Let a variable with a dot on top of it, like $\dot{w}$, refer to a non-empty set of real numbers. *This notation is nonstandard; I'm using it to reduce the number of quantifiers.*

Applying a function to a set variable $f(\dot{w})$ produces a set. If a set appears as an argument to to $<$, $\le$, ..., then the statement is true if and only if the comparison applies to every element of the set.

Here's the definition of $x_n$ given in the question

$$ x_n \stackrel{\text{def}}{=\!=} \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} \;\; \text{for all $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ } $$

We are asked to show the following. Note that $n$ only ranges over non-negative integers.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0 $$

This is equivalent to the following limit if we constrain $n$ to range over positive integers.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)} = 0 $$

In order to prove this, we start with the following fact:

$$ \forall \sigma \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \mathop. \exists \dot{w} \in \mathbb{N}_{>} \mathop. \;\;\;\; \dot{w} > \exp(\sigma) $$

In order to prove it, we pick, $1 + 3^{\lceil \sigma \rceil}$ as the minimum value of $\dot{w}$.

Since $\exp$ is monotonic increasing, its inverse $\ln$ is also monotonic increasing.

$$ \begin{align} \ln(\dot{w}) & > \ln \circ \exp(\sigma) \\\\ \ln(\dot{w}) & > \sigma \end{align} $$

Let's apply the substitution $\delta = \frac{1}{\sigma}$

$$ \forall \delta \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \mathop. \exists \dot{w} \in \mathbb{N}_{>} \mathop. \;\;\;\; \ln(\dot{w}) > \frac{1}{\delta} $$

And take the reciprocal of both sides.

$$ \frac{1}{\ln(\dot{w})} < \delta $$

Note that $\ln$, when applied to an element of $\mathbb{N}$ is always non-negative. Therefore, we can take the absolute value of the left hand side.

$$ \left| \frac{1}{\ln(\dot{w})} \right| < \delta $$

Thus, as desired

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)} = 0 \;\;\; \text{where $n$ is in $\mathbb{N}$} $$